# How to extend array or object prototype for a specific javascript object?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following:

```
function Myobj = {
   name: "Julia",
   birthdate: "xxxx",
   genres: [],
   movies: [{title: "movie1", rating: 5, genre: "Horror"}, {title: "movie2", rating 3, genre: "Comedy"},{title: "movie3", rating 3, genre: "Comedy"}, {title: "movie4", rating 3, genre: "Comedy"}, {title: "movie5", rating 3, genre: "Horror"}]
}
```

What I want to be able to do is have some function like:

```
Myobj.prototype.pushMovie(somejson) {
   // code to add somejson to "movies", and add the "genre" to the "genres" array
}
```

Such that I can go:

```
obj1 = new Myobj();
obj1.pushMovie({title: "movie1", rating: 5, genre: "Horror"});
```

Or is it better practice to override the array prototype? If so, is it possible to give a prototype a specific array as opposed to all arrays like:

```
Myobj.Array.prototype.pushMovie() {
// code to inherit from regular push, and do some operation to add to "genres"
}
```

I do not know what the syntactically correct or best approach is.

Comment: First idea is fine. No need to add to `Array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this?

```
Myobj.prototype.addMovie(somejson) {
   this.movies.push( somejson );
}
Myobj.prototype.addGenre(somejson) {
   this.genres.push( somejson );
}
Myobj.prototype.pushMovie = Myobj.prototype.addMovie;
```